# How to generate Angular component without including the "component" word in the name?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

As you may know, when executing the following Angular CLI command :

```
ng g c test
```

or its long version :

```
ng generate component test
```

Angular creates a component containing the following files :

```
CREATE src/app/test/test.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE src/app/test/test.component.html (19 bytes)
CREATE src/app/test/test.component.spec.ts (612 bytes)
CREATE src/app/test/test.component.ts (267 bytes)
```

Is there any Angular CLI option or any Angular config that allows me to not include the "component" word in file names ?

The expected result is the following :

```
CREATE src/app/test/test.css (0 bytes)
CREATE src/app/test/test.html (19 bytes)
CREATE src/app/test/test.spec.ts (612 bytes)
CREATE src/app/test/test.ts (267 bytes)
```

Comment: Do you hate your coworkers? Anyone who has to work with your codebase after you? I can think of no other reason to break from convention like this.

Comment: See in the [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#general-naming-guidelines) why it makes sense to keep the `component` word in your file names.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem that the Angular material team is respecting the convention @HereticMonkey https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/tree/main/src/app and that's okay, I think they find it less verbose this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice workaround using the `--type` option:

`ng g c test --type`

From the docs:

> --type Adds a developer-defined type to the filename, in the format "name.type.ts". [Angular generate command](https://angular.io/cli/generate)

If you don't specify a type, it will be omitted :)

By the way **this is a bad practice**. From the [General Naming Guidelines](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#general-naming-guidelines):

> Do follow a pattern that describes the symbol's feature then its type. The recommended pattern is feature.type.ts.